# Jquery Queue Change in HTML?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a piece of jquery code:

```
 $('#my_span_id').fadeOut(200).html(new_count).fadeIn(600);
```

My expectation is that this code would work as follows:
Fade out element in .2 seconds
Then change text instantly
Then fade in over .6 seconds

However it works like this:
Change text instantly
Fade out in .2 seconds
Fade in over .6 seconds

Clearly I've misunderstood how chaining works.  Any suggestions on how to get this working as expected/desired?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Chaining executes immediately (as you experienced).  If you want something to go after the fadeOut is done, then put that code in a completion function that you pass to fadeOut.

```
$('#my_span_id').fadeOut(200, function(){
   $(this).html(new_count).fadeIn(600);
});
```

You can see it work here: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/ttj2B/.

Answer (score 1):

The jquery function `html` isn't part of animation, so it doesn't get queued up with other animation effects. Instead you have to do this:

```
$('#my_span_id').fadeOut(200, function(){ 
    $(this).html(new_count).fadeIn(600);
} );
```

Here you use the callback of `fadeOut` to change the html and fade it back in.